# AttributeError: module 'transposer' has no attribute 'transpose'

Tags: python, transpose

I am running a script which needed transposer, I import that module, but it got this error:

....line 184, in  jj=transposer.transpose(i=args.v+ '/vcf_to_str/'+args.o+"TransposedStruct.str",d="\t",)

**AttributeError: module 'transposer' has no attribute 'transpose'**

Would you please help me to solve that? Thanks

Comment: Is your script named `transposer.py`? If so, you're importing that, and of course it doesn't have an atrribute `transpase`. Solution: name your script something else.

Comment: Thanks! I changed "transposer.py" name to a random name but didn't solve it! I already imported it like this:  **python3 -m pip install transposer**, then I had still error(**ImportError: cannot import name 'transpose' from partially initialized module 'transposer' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transposer/__init__.py)**) so I deleted  **init.py** and  **pycache**  from  /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transposer/